# Codeigniter HTACCESS mod rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi I want to redirect the URl:

http://localhost/invite/yK-as8_/Subhrojit_Nag

to

http://localhost/auth/accept_invitation/yK-as8_/Subhrojit_Nag

I have used the below rewrites but none of them are working. The htaccess file is in the document root path. Please help.
"

1>

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/invite

RewriteRule ^/invite/([\w\-]*)/([\w\-]*)$ /index.php/auth/accept_invitation/$1/$2
```

1.1>(since I am already using this to do away with index.php)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/invite

RewriteRule ^/invite/([\w\-]*)/([\w\-]*)$ /auth/accept_invitation/$1/$2
```

2>

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([\w\-.\/:]*)\/invite\/([\w\-]*)\/([\w\-]*)$

RewriteRule ^([\w\-.\/:]*)\/invite\/([\w\-]*)\/([\w\-]*)$ $1/index.php/auth/accept_invitation/$2/$3
```

"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configs for .htaccess file.
Remember to put it in the root where the system folder and the index.php file is.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Elkas

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
RewriteRule ^invite/(.*)$ auth/accept_invitation/$1 [R]
```

I'm not sure if there's some sort of pattern in your URL, so I use greedy match and just capture everything.

RegExr: http://regexr.com?303qt

Comment: can you tell me what the [R] stands for?

Comment: @SNAG it means to redirect the user. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r